# Which observations should I use for my panel data analysis?

Tags: regression, panel-data, dataset, descriptive-statistics, fixed-effects-model

I am currently working on my Master's thesis and for this I would like to examine the impact of the geographical location of Mutual Funds on their performance. For this I have panel data of mutual funds with their performance and the respective locations. The data is annual. I have data from 1963 up to 2022, but the data is not complete. What I mean by that is that I have data from some funds for example only from one year or from two years. From some funds I have the data over for example 10 years. From practically no funds I have the data over all years. Now I wanted to ask how best to do a panel regression (please let me know if that is the wrong approach). What is the most appropriate time period for the analysis. For example, I would have taken only data from 2000 onwards, as the data before that might be too far away and not decisive. My next question would be what funds do I take in the analysis. Should I take all of them or only those of which I have a certain number of observations over the years and how many should that be?

Your help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi, welcome to CV! I think your question hasn't gotten much attention because what you're asking is not purely about statistics but largely about substance knowledge. You probably just need to make these decisions based on what you know about the subject, the history of Fund development and the exact nature and amount of missingness. I would start by asking myself 1) what time period would be reasonable for your research question and 2) for how many Funds you have complete or near-complete data for this time period?